# Display all employee and company names of location with most companies

Tags: mysql, sql

Recently I received this question on a test and I cannot reach a solution even after trying it on my own after the test was done.

I have 3 tables:

```
PEOPLE
+----+-------+----------+
| ID |  NAME |COMPANY_ID|
+------------+----------+
| 1  |George |    C1    | 
| 2  | Jim   |    C2    |
| 3  | John  |    C3    |  
+----+-------+----------+

COMPANY
+----------------+-----------+
| ID |    NAME   |LOCATION_ID|
+----------------+-----------+
| C1 |Water-Based|    L1     | 
| C2 |Gas-Giant  |    L1     |
| C3 |Fire-Proof |    L2     |  
+----+-----------+-----------+

LOCATION
+----+-----------+
| ID | COMPANY_ID|
+----+-----------+
| L1 |     C1    | 
| L1 |     C2    |
| L2 |     C3    |  
+----+-----------+
```

The goal is to determine which location has the most companies, then, display the name of the employees for the companies on that location as well as the location they work in.

I have tried to do a subquery where I count the number of times a location occurs within the COMPANY table and then display the people that work there as well as the company, but I can't seem to get it right, this is my code:

```
SELECT PEOPLE.NAME AS EMPLOYEE, t.NAME AS COMPANY
FROM(SELECT *,COUNT(LOCATION_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY LOCATION_ID) AS LCOUNT FROM COMPANY) AS t
JOIN PEOPLE
ON PEOPLE.COMPANY_ID = t.ID;
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
+------+-----------+
| NAME |  COMPANY  |
+------------------+
|George|Water-Based| 
|Jim   |Gas-Giant  |  
+------+-----------+
```

Any help and advice are highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and SHOUTING won't get an answer any faster. It's also rather impolite to shout at us when you're asking us for free help to solve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the data model. If there were just the tables `people` and `company`, a company would reside in one location (1:n relation). But there is also the table `location`. If there wasn't the column `location_id` in `company`, this would mean a company can reside in many locations (m:n relation). What does that mix mean? A company can reside in many locations, but has one main location, maybe? Or is this a typo, and there actually is no `company_id` in `location`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach will first find all location that have the lost companys,even when there are many and then diplay all employees with their company

> ```
> SELECT P.NAME AS namy,
>        C.NAME AS company
> FROM COMPANY C
> JOIN PEOPLE P ON C.ID=P.COMPANY_ID
> WHERE LOCATION_ID IN(
> SELECT 
> `ID` 
> FROM LOCATION
>  GROUP BY `ID`
>  HAVING COUNT(*) 
>  = (SELECT   COUNT(*)  FROM LOCATION GROUP BY `ID` ORDEr By COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1))
> ```
>
> ```
> PEOPLE_NAME | COMPANY_NAME
> :---------- | :-----------
> George      | Water-Based 
> Jim         | Gas-Giant
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b3c02bdaf17fab518004b0b7fb7ef18e)*

Answer (score 0):

You can do a subquery finding `LOCATION_ID` with the most companies then use that in `WHERE` for query that join `COMPANY` and `PEOPLE` table.

Try this:

```
SELECT P.NAME AS PEOPLE_NAME,
       C1.NAME AS COMPANY_NAME
FROM COMPANY C1
JOIN PEOPLE P ON C1.ID=P.COMPANY_ID
  WHERE C1.LOCATION_ID=(SELECT LOCATION_ID
                 FROM COMPANY C2 
                 GROUP BY C2.LOCATION_ID
                ORDER BY COUNT(ID) DESC LIMIT 1);
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e5729c6e2d942b24efb77b20c542bd04)

I think the table `LOCATION` is not necessary at all (as a table or in the query) since it's basically the same thing as `COMPANY` table; both having matching company and location `ID`. Unless the `LOCATION` table is storing unique location `ID` and with it's own location `NAME` and you want to show it in the result, perhaps if the `LOCATION` table is like this:

```
LOCATION
+----+------------+
| ID |     NAME   |
+----+------------+
| L1 | Location_1 | 
| L2 | Location_2 |
| L3 | Location_3 |  
.....
+----+-----------+
```

Then : [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=81e004281dfa8cc902612afff9bdd44c)